# VBScript to copy a numerical values from a doc file and paste it on a excel file

Tags: vbscript

i want to open a doc file using Vbscript and then find a string which contain some value as in table format then copy that value and paste it on a excel file

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using VBA/Macros for this. For more information on VBA click here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ff688774.aspx

A sample VBA macro that copies data from Word to Excel can be found here:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0a73df0b-096b-40eb-a65a-9b16bc6a57ed/need-macro-to-copy-text-from-word-to-excel-help?forum=word

If you go down the path of working with VBA/Macros, it is extremely helpful to turn on the Developer tab in the ribbon in office apps. You can turn this on by clicking File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon -> Then check the Developer box on the right.